# Comparing email records between two tables

Tags: sql, comparison, not-exists

I am trying to compare a table of users from one DB
and check whether that Email Address exists in our **Dynamics CRM user base**

I have the table `User_V` from that other interface,
and I created the following query, but it only gives me the results which are `useremail = NULL`
and I am only trying to find those who exist in `user_v` and not in `[SystemUserBase]`

```
 select *
       from [HSchool].[dbo].[user_v] as u
       where   not exists (select InternalEMailAddress
       from [HrProd_MSCRM].[dbo].[SystemUserBase] as inn 
where ltrim (rtrim (LOWER (u.useremail))) collate database_default <> ltrim (rtrim (LOWER(inn.InternalEMailAddress))))
```

I hope I am as clear as possible,
thank you in advance!

Comment: `=` instead of `<>`?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a double negative.

> select *
>          from [HSchool].[dbo].[user_v] as u
>          where   not exists (select InternalEMailAddress
>          from [HrProd_MSCRM].[dbo].[SystemUserBase] as inn 
>   where ltrim (rtrim (LOWER (u.useremail))) collate database_default <> ltrim (rtrim (LOWER(inn.InternalEMailAddress)))

This query finds records that does not match.

Then there is a "Not Exist" above that.
Amending the "Where" clause in the sub-query to an equate should work